# Parameter not set after validating form in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I pass a variable `$id` by URL, and load the data in the form form update but when I am going to validate the form , the value `$id` is not recognized.

```
function myfunction() {
    $id = $this->uri->segment(4); 
    echo $id;   //yes, print the value  

    $data_user = $this->admin_model->query_data_user($id);
    $direccion = $data_user[0]->address;
    $phone = $data_user[0]->phone;

    $this->data['address'] = array(
            'name' => 'address',
            'id' => 'address',
            'value' => $address,
            'class' => 'input',
    );

    $this->data['phone'] = array(
            'name' => 'phone',
            'id' => 'phone',
            'value' => $phone,
            'class' => 'input',
    );

    echo $id;  //yes, print the value

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address', 'xss_clean|max_length[100]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone', 'required|xss_clean|max_length[20]|is_natural_no_zero');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
        echo $id;  //here NOT PRINT $id
        $data = array(
                'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
                'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
        );

        $id = $this->uri->segment(4); 
        echo $id;  //here not print the value $id

        $this->ion_auth->update_user($id, $data); 
        $this->load->view('includes/template_mensajes', $data);
    }
    $this->load->view('users/update_user', $this->data);
}
```

The value `$id` is not recognized when it's validated my form, what is my error?

Comment: Did you try to make the variable $id global ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where are you submitting your form to. Are you sure you are passing the ID in the URI on your form's action attribute.

For example your form open tag should look something like

`<form action="/admin/myfunction/<?= $id ?>">`

Or using the codeigniter helper

`echo form_open('admin/myfunction/' . $id);`

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your answer.  You has answered my question.

Comment: I think this is part of the answer, and is the only way to accomplish what I explained in my answer. But  more importantly using $this->uri->segment(4); in his code is wrong and should be done using the proper method for CI's controller actions.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken and myfunction is an action in your controller called ... "mycontroller" let's say. Then you should just be sending this url: `http://localhost/mycontroller/myfunction/1234`

And update your action as accepting the ID paramter $id. CodeIgniter will take care of the rest.

```
function myfunction($id) {
...
}
```

Comment: I tried with your answer:  anchor('user/myfunction/'.$user['id'], 'update') and my function function myfunction ($id) and generates this errors:  A PHP Error was encountered.  Severity: Warning.  
Message: Missing argument 1 for user::myfunction().  Filename: controllers/user.php an other error is this:  A PHP Error was encountered.  Severity: Notice.  Message: Undefined variable: id.  
Filename: controllers/user.php.  I would like that this option works for me.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I can to pass the value based in your answer, however, in the ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {  is not recognized the value $id; .  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass that $id variable in form as hidden field and get it back as POST value.

Answer (score 0):

After adding my id to the end of my URL, e.g. `www.whsconcepts.com/?id=100`,
I call it back inside my form.  For example:

```
form_open('the url I want' . $_Get ['id'])
```